# Retrieve Dynamic Array list from Parse.com in Android

Tags: android, parse-platform

![enter image description here][1]I am a beginner with Android, I am using Parse.com backend to store and retrieve information in my app. The problem is I want to retrieve list of people with their names and profession however I am able to retrieve only detail of one person I have multiple people, but its showing only one record in my textviews, I should use listview but I don't understand adapters. I tried implementing after following tutorials but they wont work. Please tell me how do I retrieve multiple records or dynamically load textviews from parse.com in my app activity.

//showdata activity shows record for only 1 person but I have multiple records

```
public class ShowData extends ActionBarActivity {
    Button Bsearch;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_data);
        Parse.initialize(this, "keys", "keys");


        // Uses a layout with a ListView (id: "listview"), which uses our Adapter.

        Bsearch= (Button) findViewById(R.id.Bsearch);


        Bsearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {



               ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Pro");
                query.whereEqualTo("City", "Pune");
                query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
                    public void done(ParseObject emp, ParseException e) {
                        if (emp == null) {
                            Toast.makeText(ShowData.this,"Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } else {
                            String n =emp.getString("Name");
                            String prof= emp.getString("Professional");
                            //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"User"+un+"\n Password"+pwd,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            TextView t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TVresult);
                            t.setText(""+n);

                            TextView t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TVresult1);
                            t1.setText("" + prof);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });


    }


}
```

//edited query not working

```
  Bsearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Pro");
            query.whereEqualTo("City", "Pune");
            query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
                public void done(List<ParseObject> emp, ParseException e) {
                    if (e == null) {
                        String n =emp.getString("Name");
                        String prof= emp.getString("Professional");
                        Toast.makeText(ShowData.this,"success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        TextView t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TVresult);
                        t.setText(""+n);

                        TextView t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TVresult1);
                        t1.setText("" + prof);
                    } else {
                        Log.d("score", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxUqv.png

I managed to fix emp object error however while i hit search button app crashes and i get pop up unfortunately app has stopped here is the logcat

```
    04-24 18:39:34.208    4280-4280/com.example.sangram.nearbyapp E/Trace﹕ error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
04-24 18:39:34.432    4280-4280/com.example.sangram.nearbyapp E/ResourceType﹕ Style contains key with bad entry: 0x01010479
04-24 18:40:05.836    4280-4280/com.example.sangram.nearbyapp E/ResourceType﹕ Style contains key with bad entry: 0x01010479
04-24 18:40:08.397    4280-4280/com.example.sangram.nearbyapp E/ResourceType﹕ Style contains key with bad entry: 0x01010479
04-24 18:40:08.443    4280-4280/com.example.sangram.nearbyapp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sangram.nearbyapp/com.example.sangram.nearbyapp.ShowData}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:149)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1300)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
            at android.app.ListActivity.onContentChanged(ListActivity.java:243)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:261)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1867)
            at com.example.sangram.nearbyapp.ShowData.onCreate(ShowData.java:68)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5020)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:149)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1300)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: At a quick glance it looks like you are on the right path. have you tried this tutorial: https://parse.com/tutorials/parse-query-adapter ?

Comment: cYrixmorten yes i saw parse query adapter but couldnt understand :(

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `getFirstInBackground` which will return only one record.
Change your query to:

```
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
     public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
         if (e == null) {
             objectsWereRetrievedSuccessfully(objects);
         } else {
             objectRetrievalFailed();
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Yep, and he keeps updating the same two TextViews, so even with this correction it likely still only shows one result.

Comment: sorry i am a beginner shall i use list? i will try this query

Comment: What you are doing is fetching only one result while you want to get a list of objects. As @cYrixmorten rightly pointed out you are overwriting your text views even if you get the list of objects.

Comment: so shall i add listview ?

Comment: Thats your implementation how and what you want to do with your data.

Comment: could someone plz elaborate how to use query for displaying multiple records in list i am complete beginner i am getting errors

Comment: i am pasting new query plz tell me what changes should i do

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to achieve the Dynamic Listview.
You can checkout this tutorial. It will be helpful.

http://www.pcsalt.com/android/listview-using-baseadapter-android/

Answer (score 0):

This should work, you were only calling for one result back and you did not have a for loop to go through you objects.  I tried editing your code, take a look and let me know if it works:

```
public void updateMegaMillionsData() {
    ParseQuery<GameDataParseClass> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Pro");
    query.whereEqualTo("City", "Pune");
    query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> emp, ParseException e) {
            if (emp != null) {

                String n = String.valueOf(emp.get("Name"));
                String prof= String.valueOf(emp.get("Professional"));
                Toast.makeText(ShowData.this, "success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                TextView t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TVresult);
                t.setText(""+n);

                TextView t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TVresult1);
                t1.setText("" + prof);
            }
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: James Jones I tried your query and emp is my object of type list however its showing error i am attaching screenshot plz check it

Comment: James plz go through the attached screenshot link

Comment: Hey  Sangram, Are you trying to retrieve a list of objects or just one object?

Comment: no only one object which stores name and professional for each record

Comment: James I managed to fixed emp object issue it should be like String n =emp.get(i).getString("Name"); however when i click on button it to show list it craches i am adding log cat sir please help me fix this issue

Comment: I'm here, no worries, what does your logcat say?

Comment: Sir I have just added it you can check it

Comment: thanks i tried it but that isnt the problem still if i run the app it crashes same as the previous logcat

Comment: James how do i get rid of    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sangram.nearbyapp/com.example.sangram.nearbyapp.ShowData}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
  i am using Textviews to display results but it should load result in list object that is emp now what to do about it coz it is the reason why app crashed

Comment: can you post your xml files? both the list and the one where you have your textviews?